# Looking for clarification on "running" Tensorflow models

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

from Tensorflow's documentation, there seems to be a large array of options for "running", serving, testing, and predicting using a Tensorflow model.  I've made a model very similar to MNIST, where it outputs a distribution from an image.  ***For a beginner,* what would be the easiest way to take one or a few images, and send them through the model, getting an output prediction?**  It is mostly for experimentation purposes.  Sorry if this is too redundant, but all my research has led me to so many different ways of doing this and the documentation doesn't really give any info on the *pros and cons* of the different methods.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using placeholders for your model input and then using feed_dict to feed values into your model.

If that's the case the simplest way would be after you have a trained model you save it using tf.saver. Then you can have a test script where you restore your model and then sess.run on your output variable with a feed_dict of whatever you want your input to be.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to figure out how to user tf.saver eventually.  I'm just a bit slow.